# Is sudo gdisk sdX dangerous?

Tags: gdisk

I need to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode, but for this thing I need to convert disk to GPT. Will command sudo gdisk X erase all data from HDD?
Thanks for answer in advance!

Comment: Some of the available commands in `gdisk` will overwrite the partition table and make the [previous/current] data very difficult to access. It is a very powerful but also dangerous tool. You had better **backup your data** to another drive before using `gdisk`.

Comment: Oh! Hard to backup 200GB :( Thanks for answer

Comment: It is a general rule to backup at the very least all data, that you cannot afford to lose. There can be several causes of data loss, not only mistakes with dangerous tools, but also hardware failures, that can happen without a warning. I suggest that you get a *backup drive (for example a USB hard disk drive)*, and backup all your personal data files to that drive. Before you get such a drive, maybe you can backup the most important data to some cloud service or USB pendrive.

Comment: @sudodus Thanks for regarding information :) For my security I will back up necessary data

Comment: ... and after you have backed up the important data, good luck with `gdisk` :-)

Comment: Thanks! I started hating Windows and wish to use Ubuntu. I am newbie and there are many things to discover :)

Answer (score 0):

*In theory,* converting a disk from MBR to GPT form will not damage the data contained within the disk's partitions; *however,* there are several important caveats:

- As suggested by the comments to your question, `gdisk` is a powerful tool, and with that power comes the potential for problems, both in the form of bugs and user error. It's usually possible to overcome problems created by `gdisk` (or by MBR-to-GPT conversions accomplished in other ways), but doing so usually requires a great deal of expertise.
- Sometimes an MBR-to-GPT operation is not possible without data loss. This typically happens when the final partition extends right up to the end of the disk. Because GPT uses the last few sectors (normally 33) to store backup data structures, any partition that fills that area will conflict, and will need to be deleted or resized for an MBR-to-GPT conversion to succeed. GPT fdisk recognizes this problem and should refuse to convert such a disk unless you delete that final partition (or resize it in another utility), but if you delete a necessary partition or if there are problems resizing it, you can lose data.
- If the disk is currently used to boot an OS in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, then converting it to GPT form is likely to render the existing OS unbootable. It's often (but not always) possible to recover the existing OS's bootability by installing an EFI-mode boot loader, but details vary from one OS to another. If the computer boots Windows in BIOS mode, Microsoft's [MBR2GPT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt) utility is probably the way to go. This will do an MBR-to-GPT conversion, similar to what GPT fdisk can do; but it will also create an ESP, install the Windows EFI-mode boot loader, and resize partitions as necessary for these goals. I've never used MBR2GPT, so I can't comment on it in more detail, though. As I understand it, the tool works for Windows 10; I don't know how it reacts to other versions of Windows or how it would react if the disk currently boots Windows along with other OS(es).
- Post-conversion, not all OSes understand GPT. If you expect to access the disk only from Ubuntu, or from Ubuntu and another modern OS (like Windows Vista or later, any Intel- and M1-based version of macOS, or a modern FreeBSD), then you'll be fine. If the disk must be accessed from an old or obscure OS (say, Windows 95, OS/2, or DOS), then you should research compatibility before proceeding. These OSes likely lack native GPT support, although third-party GPT drivers might exist for some.

All in all, the advice in the comments to your question is good: Before performing an MBR-to-GPT conversion, or any other major partitioning tasks, it's best to back up your data. If you lack adequate backup capabilities, remedy that problem. Removable hard disks are great for this task, and backup software for all major OSes is readily available, often for free.

I would also ask why you want to convert to GPT. If your computer is currently booting in BIOS mode, then it can almost certainly boot Ubuntu in that way, too. This may be perfectly adequate, even if it's not the new technological shininess. OTOH, using GPT and/or EFI-mode booting may offer advantages, like support for larger hard disks and a boost in security through Secure Boot. The question didn't give enough detail to evaluate these issues, so I can't offer an opinion beyond suggesting that the benefits and risks of a conversion need to be considered against the benefits and risks of continuing to use MBR and BIOS-mode booting.